# android- How to use startActivityforResults() in tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am new to tabs concept. In my app one tab have the navigation to the multiple Activities. Here some cases I need the result of the child activity so I want to use the `startActivityforresult()` method. I tried I am not getting please can anybody help me.

code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), RB_StateMList.class);       
startActivityForResult(intent,GET_SEL_STATES_LIST);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override **onActivityResult** in either your `Activity` or `ActivityGroup` in order to receive results back from other activity. See below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: i override onActivityResult() in activity not in activitygroup.is any problem with this?

Comment: do it in ActivityGroup because that is the one which is hosting tabs

Comment: How to use the startActivityforResult()? it means above code is right?

Comment: yes, just paste the above code in your *ActivityGroup* and then match **requestCode** with **GET_SEL_STATES_LIST** to observe the results

Comment: But how to get the views of the activity to activitygroup. It means A1, A2 are two activities. A1 is dependent on the A2 result. A2 return the result now i want to set that text to textview of A1 activity. In this case how to get the view into activitygroup.

Comment: It depends on your design pattern. I'm using ActivityGroup but without using Activities as tabs. and it helps me to update tabs from ActivityGroup easily